# Retrieve mysql value from php for radio buttons not working

Tags: php

I have table address in my database. I put the value=$Id; for my radio button but I have no idea why it's not working. No error shown make me even confuse and I need help since I am still new to php. When I put 2 address and I checked the radio button the address did not change. It only take the latest one that user inserted.

```
$userid=$_SESSION["userID"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer where ID='$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query( $con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $Id=$row['Id'];
  $OrderID=$row['OrderID'];
  $ID=$row['ID'];
  $Name=$row['Name'];
  $Email=$row['Email'];
  $Address=$row['Address'];
  $PostalCode=$row['PostalCode'];
  $City=$row['City'];
  $State=$row['State'];
  $mobile=$row['mobile_number'];
  //    $total=$total+$pSubtotal;
  //    $totalWeight=$totalWeight+$subWeight;
  echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"select\" value=\"$Id\"> <label>$Name</label><br>";
  echo "$Address<br>";
  echo "$PostalCode $City<br>";
  echo "$State";
  echo "<div>&nbsp;</div>";
  echo "<img src=\"images/phone-icon.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\"> $mobile<br>";
  echo "<img src=\"images/email.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\"> $Email<br>";
  echo "<div>&nbsp;</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-lg-12\" style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;\"></div>";
}




if(isset($_POST["pay"])){
    $userid=$_SESSION["userID"];

    $final_price=$_POST["final_price"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];

    $email=$_POST["email"];

    $postcode=$_POST["postcode"];
    //echo $postcode;

    $mobile_number=$_POST["mobile_number"];
    //echo $name;
    $radio=$_POST['select'];
    if(isset($radio)){


        $sql="select Id,Name,mobile_number,Email,Address,PostalCode,City,State from customer where Id='$radio'";
        echo $sql;
                $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                    $idx=$rows['Id'];
                    $name=$rows['Name'];
                    $mobile=$rows['mobile_number'];
                    $email=$rows['Email'];
                    $address=$rows['Address'];
                    $postcode=$rows['PostalCode'];
                    $city=$rows['City'];
                    $state=$rows['State'];

                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you submiting those information?
You just select the desired radio and press Submit?

Another point is, you do have 2 lines doing the same thing:

```
$Id=$row['Id'];
$ID=$row['ID'];
```

You should avoid those kind of thing.
Use the correct uppercase/lowercase according to your database table field name.

Did you use a var_dump($row) to check the correct case ?
That can be the problem.

Comment: yes I have a submit button. $Id=$row['Id'];
$ID=$row['ID']; I don't think his is the problem because it's just a variable and ID is actually ID for something else.

Comment: So you are saying that you have 2 different ID fields with "same" name, just with different cases?
Anyway, did you try the var_dump($row) ?

Comment: no. I just echo $sql; to see whether the Id is passed or not. and I get this select Id,Name,mobile_number,Email,Address,PostalCode,City,State from customer where Id='7'

Comment: Use the var_dump on the $row to see what is returning from your select

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not the right answer, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but I *think* you mean to use an associative array? Try using mysqli_fetch_assoc.